# Error converting data type varchar to float in running trigger who calls SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table which has a trigger that will call a certain SP that parses the string thrown by the trigger.

Here are the strings thrown by the trigger

**351856040520298,241111;1G,141007024755,A,1437.2453N,12100.2887E,3.10,206,0.8,21010000;2G,141007024755,10,43.6,14.08,00.18,273295019.6**

**351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9**

as you can see they differ in length So i switch the trigger to call a the SP if the length is match.

Here's my trigger

```
USE [SMSGPS]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CallSPGPRSIN]    Script Date: 11/17/2014 9:43:44 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CallSPGPRSIN]
 ON [dbo].[GPRSIN]
 AFTER INSERT
 AS BEGIN
 DECLARE @smsgpsmessage varchar(500);
 DECLARE @smslen varchar(10);
 DECLARE @const varchar(10);
 DECLARE @const1 varchar(10);
 DECLARE @const2 varchar(10);
 DECLARE @const3 varchar(10);
 DECLARE @const4 varchar(10);
 DECLARE @const5 varchar(10);
 SET @smsgpsmessage = (SELECT TOP 1 smsmsg FROM GPRSIN order by smsdt desc);
 SET @smslen = (SELECT LEN(@smsgpsmessage));
 SET @const = '130';
 SET @const1 = '131';
 SET @const2 = '132';
 SET @const3 = '133';
 SET @const4 = '134';
 SET @const5 = '135';

 if @smslen = @const OR @smslen = @const1 OR @smslen = @const2 OR @smslen = @const3 OR @smslen = @const4 OR @smslen = @const5
     EXEC ParsingProcedureRX8 @ProductCode = @smsgpsmessage;
 END
```

I don't know if this is right or wrong but it does run only and only if the length is 134 or 133.

Now it will call the SP as stated in the last part of the trigger and here's the SP

```
USE [SMSGPS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ParsingProcedureRX8]    Script Date: 11/17/2014 11:00:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParsingProcedureRX8]
@ProductCode VARCHAR(500)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 INSERT INTO tblKMRUN2(Account,TrxDateTime,PhilTime, Lat, Long, Speed2, DeviceStatus, Engine,  
  KmRun, ProcStatus) 
SELECT [Account]  = LEFT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX(',',@ProductCode) - 1),
   [TrxDateTime] = cast(stuff(stuff(stuff((SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 27, 12)), 7,0,' '), 10,0,':'), 13,0,':') as datetime),
   [PhilTime] = cast(stuff(stuff(stuff((SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 27, 12)), 7,0,' '), 10,0,':'),13,0,':') as datetime),
   [Lat] = cast(SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 42, 9) as float)/100,
   [Long] = cast(SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 53, 10) as float)/100,
   [Speed2] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 65, 1),
   [statcode] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 8),
   [ENGINE] = CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 1) = '2')
                THEN 'ON'
                 ELSE 'OFF' END,
   [KM2] = round(cast(right(@ProductCode, 11)as float)/3600, 0, 1),
   [ProcStatus] = '0';
```

When I try inserting the second string which is the

**351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9**

it returns an error which says,

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure ParsingProcedureRX8, Line 5
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

but when I try using the other string it does not return an error at all

POlease help.

Thanks.

Comment: You know that triggers are a mass operation reflected through  the data in `inserted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stored procedure  the Input

```
351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9
```

for the below query

```
[statcode] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 8)
```

Return:

```
000006;2
```

Which cannot be converted to `Float`.

Try to pass the input correctly.

For the first input the value for `[statecode] is 21010000` which can be converted to float But, the second input value is `000006;2` which cannot be converted to `float`.

Use the below query to check if the values get from the @ProductCode is correct or not.

Assign your input to `'SET @ProductCode'`

```
DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(500)
SET @ProductCode = '351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9'
SELECT 
    [Account]  = LEFT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX(',',@ProductCode) - 1),
    [TrxDateTime] = cast(stuff(stuff(stuff((SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 27, 12)), 7,0,' '), 10,0,':'), 13,0,':') as datetime),
    [PhilTime] = cast(stuff(stuff(stuff((SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 27, 12)), 7,0,' '), 10,0,':'),13,0,':') as datetime),
    [Lat] = cast(SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 42, 9) as float)/100,
    [Long] = cast(SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 53, 10) as float)/100,
    [Speed2] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 65, 1),
    [statcode] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 8),
    [ENGINE] = CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 1) = '2')
                THEN 'ON'
                 ELSE 'OFF' END,
    [KM2] = round(cast(right(@ProductCode, 11)as float)/3600, 0, 1),
    [ProcStatus] = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfect with any change.
I recommend you to upgrade your query to this

```
USE [SMSGPS]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CallSPGPRSIN]    Script Date: 11/17/2014 9:43:44 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CallSPGPRSIN]
 ON [dbo].[GPRSIN]
 AFTER INSERT
 AS BEGIN
 DECLARE @smsgpsmessage varchar(500);
 DECLARE @smslen varchar(10);

 SET @smsgpsmessage = (SELECT TOP 1 smsmsg FROM GPRSIN order by smsdt desc);
 SET @smslen = (SELECT LEN(@smsgpsmessage));

 if (@smslen between 130 and 135)
     EXEC ParsingProcedureRX8 @ProductCode = @smsgpsmessage;
 END
```